# VSTO for Office 2010 Globals.Thisaddin is always null

Tags: vba, powerpoint, vsto, office-2010

I have a Powerpoint addin, which when I need to reference `Globals.ThisAddin.Application` (the current instance or active instance of powerpoint calling to the addin) It returns a null reference. I do need `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application' or another method to get the current active instance of Powerpoint because it is used to generate something in the active presentation's active slide.

#### Watches

I tried using watches to track the error, but it says the following.

[image: Current Watches]

### Code

#### VBA

```vb
Private Sub tst()
Dim tmp As object
Set tmp = New object
tmp.dosomething ' error triggered is here
Set tmp = Nothing
End Sub
```

#### Simplified VB.NET

##### ThisAddin

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint
Imports System.Diagnostics
Public Class ThisAddIn
    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
    End Sub

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

    End Sub

End Class
```

##### Custom Namespace and Class

```vb
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Ppt = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

Namespace CustomStuff

    <ComVisible(True)> _
    <InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)> _
    Public Interface IObject
        Sub DoSomething()
    End Interface


    <ComVisible(True)> _
    <ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
    Public Class Obj
        Implements IObject
        <ComVisible(True)>
        Public Sub DoSomething() Implements IObject.DoSomething
            Dim cpres As Ppt.Presentation  
            cpres = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation ' <- error is here
            With cpres.Slides(cpres.Windows(1).Selection.SlideRange.SlideIndex)
            ...
            End With
        End Sub
        Private Sub New()

        End Sub
        <ComVisible(True)>
        Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
            MyBase.Finalize()
        End Sub
    End Class

End Namespace
```

### Software And IDE

[image: Currently Available Software]

Comment: Do you develop a VSTO based add-in?

Comment: yes, I need to use the code in vba.

Comment: VBA doesn't have access to the Globals class.

Comment: Sorry, Let me rephrase I need to use the _CustomStuff.obj_ in vba, but it it needs to create something in the active presentation. then i create an instance of _CustomStuff.obj_ in vba.

Comment: The `Globals.ThisAddIn` property is available for VSTO add-ins only. You need to use COM automation to get the PP running instance at runtime.

Comment: Any Ideas on where to find information on doing that? Every time I find something, It never works.

Comment: You need to post a separate question where you could explain what you are trying to do and ask how to get an Application instance where you need it.

Comment: VSTO add-ins don't have `Globals.ThisAddIn` set to null.

Answer (score 1):

The `ThisAddIn` class comes from a VSTO Add-in project. You can access this object by using the `Globals.ThisAddIn` property. But I don't see the code of add-in in your sample. It seems you are trying to use the `Application` property outside of boundaries of the add-in.

See [Global access to objects in Office projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/global-access-to-objects-in-office-projects?view=vs-2022) for more information.

Comment: do you mean should do```imports project.namespace.``` in _"ThisAddin.vb"_?